# Recursive Depth First Search for finding valid sudoku boards in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku, depth-first-search

I am not an experienced programmer, and I decided to make a program that could find all possible sudoku arrangements just for fun. As far as I can see, the program is working all right, but I'd like to know how could I improve it, since there are some parts that are a little "polluted". Specially the way I deal with the blocks of the board.

```
#####################################################################################
### Sudoku Valid Boards Generator using recursive depth-first search approach     ###
### by Anderson Freixo                                                            ###
### anderson.freixo@gmail.com                                                     ### 
#####################################################################################

## The board is represented by lists of lists from board[0][0] to board[9][9].
## There are three functions which tests the rules for choosing a valid number in sudoku.
## Then, after we call the search function for the first time, and it checks for valid numbers
## it calls itself again adding the new valid number to the board.
## (The commented prints are just for debugging) 

blocks = []
solutions = []

for n in range(3):                                                                      #Initializes the 'blocks' list which contains the groups
  for m in range(3):                                                                    #of positions of each of the nine blocks of the game
    blocks.append(list(itertools.product((0+3*n,1+3*n,2+3*n),(0+3*m,1+3*m,2+3*m))))     #the result is a list of 9 lists with 9 tuples each 
                                                                                        #containing the position
                                                                                        #(I know it's really awkward, but I couldn't think of a clear
                                                                                        # and fast way of doing it)

                                                               #Functions to test the selected number: 

def is_in_line(num, board, line):                              # #1 - Is the number already in the line?
    if num in board[line]:                                 
        #print("Number", num, "already in the line!")
        return True


def is_in_column(num, board, line, column):                    # #2 - Is the number already in the column?
  for line_idx in range(len(board)):                              
       if line_idx < line: 
         if board[line_idx][column] == num:
            #print("Number", num, "already in the column!")
            return True


def is_in_block(num, board, line, column):                     # #3 - Is the number already in the block?
    global blocks

    for block in blocks:                                        
      if (line, column) in block:                              # First finds out to which block the current position belongs to                
        myblock = block
        break

    for l, c in myblock:                                       # Then, tests if the position is filled                             
      if l < len(board) and c < len(board[l]):                 # and checks if the number in the position
        if board[l][c] == num:                                 # is the number being tested
            #print("Number", num, "in the same block!")
            return True


def search(board):
  if len(solutions) > 1000: return                             # Just a random limit for the program to stop
                                                               # (there are more than 6x10**21 possible solutions) 

  global solutions                                             # If the board is complete, than this board is a solution 
  if len(board) == 9 and len(board[8]) == 9:
    print("A solution was found!")
    solutions.append(board)
    print("Solution n.", len(solutions),":")
    print(board)
    return

  myboard = list(board)                                        #   I had to create this new board to be able to append a new line in the board
                                                               #   without interfering in the original one. This is necessary when the  
                                                               #   length of the line is 9 because of the situation below. 

  next_line = len(board)-1                                     #   Finds out which is the next position to evaluate
  if len(board[next_line]) == 9:                               #   Filling up one line at a time. If the line has been filled
    next_line+=1                                               #   (length = 9) then the position to be analyzed must be  
    myboard.append([])                                         #   line+1 column 0.           
    next_column = 0                                            #   (If I didn't append the empty list, there would be problems
  else:                                                        #   regarding the index range in the test functions)
    next_column = len(board[next_line])

  for n in range(1,10):                                        #   If any of the tests return True, skip to the next iteration                                  
    if is_in_line(n, myboard, next_line): continue
    if is_in_column(n, myboard, next_line, next_column): continue
    if is_in_block(n, myboard, next_line, next_column): continue

                                                               #   Otherwise...                                            
    new_board = copy.deepcopy(myboard)                         #   Create a new board with the valid number in it                      
    new_board[next_line].append(n)                             #   (Found it necessary to generate a deep copy, otherwise all the new numbers
    search(new_board)                                          #   would be added to the same list)
                                                               #   and then call the function again      

  return

search([[]])                                                   #   starts the search with an empty board
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Style

Your indentation is variable, some times 2 spaces, some times 4. I suggest you stick to 4 as per [PEP8 conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). `continue`s on the same line than the `if`s feels also odd.

Most of your comments can be converted into docstrings. This give more valuable information that can be accessed at runtime too (*e.g.* using the `help` builtin in a python shell).

In the same vein, some magic variable such as `__author__` or `__credits__` can have more meaning than a comment.

Compare the `help` on your module:

```
Help on module sudoku_depth_first_solver_original:

NAME
    sudoku_depth_first_solver_original

DESCRIPTION
    #####################################################################################
    ### Sudoku Valid Boards Generator using recursive depth-first search approach     ###
    ### by Anderson Freixo                                                            ###
    ### anderson.freixo@gmail.com                                                     ### 
    #####################################################################################

FUNCTIONS
    is_in_block(num, board, line, column)

    is_in_column(num, board, line, column)

    is_in_line(num, board, line)

    search(board)

DATA
    blocks = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2,...
    m = 2
    n = 2
    solutions = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]...

FILE
    /home/mettinger/code_testing/codereview/sudoku_depth_first_solver_original.py
```

with the `help` on a rewrite I present latter:

```
Help on module sudoku_depth_first_solver:

NAME
    sudoku_depth_first_solver - Sudoku Valid Boards Generator

DESCRIPTION
    This module is using a recursive depth-first search approach
    to generate every valid board from a starting template.

FUNCTIONS
    find_block(line, column)
        Retrieve the block which contain the cell at the given line and column

    initialize(board)
        Ensure a board has at least 9 lines and 9 columns

    is_in_block(num, board, line, column)
        Test if the given number lies in the given block of the given board

    is_in_column(num, board, column)
        Test if the given number lies in the given column of the given board

    is_in_line(num, board, line)
        Test if the given number lies in the given line of the given board

    search(board)
        Generate all valid solutions that can fit in the given board

DATA
    BLOCKS = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2,...

AUTHOR
    Anderson Freixo <anderson.freixo@gmail.com>

CREDITS
    Contributors:
     * Mathias Ettinger (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger)

FILE
    /home/mettinger/code_testing/codereview/sudoku_depth_first_solver.py
```

Lastly, the last line (`search([[]])`) should be under an [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) clause.

## Itertools

You know how to use this module so you could came up with that yourself, but your two `for` loops to build the `block` constant are essentially `itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)`. So you can write:

```
blocks = []

for n, m in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2):
    blocks.append(list(itertools.product((0+3*n,1+3*n,2+3*n),(0+3*m,1+3*m,2+3*m))))
```

which, in turn, can be a list-comprehension to better highlight the fact that `blocks` is a constant (so better name it ALL_CAPS, now we’re at it):

```
BLOCKS = [
    list(itertools.product(
        (3*n, 3*n + 1, 3*n + 2),
        (3*m, 3*m + 1, 3*m + 2),
    )) for n, m in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)
]
```

## Searching for numbers

- It's very redundant to `return True` in an `if` block (and `return False` in the associated `else` or implicitly `return None`), just return the value of the boolean you compute.
- You do not need to know the number of lines in the board beforehand to search for a number in a column. Just iterate over each line and get the column<sup>th</sup> number.
- You can extract a function searching for the right block to simplify the function searching for a number in a block.

## Simplifications

If you consider that valid boards always have 9 rows and 9 columns, you do not need to worry about `IndexError`s. As such, I would suggest writting a function that ensure that and fill the board with `None` in case it isn't the right size.

After that, all what's left is to use indexes in your recursion rather than computing `len`gths. An helper function dedicated to the recursion called by `search` with initial parameters could be of great use here.

I would also consider using generators instead of filling lists of results. The advantage here is that, if you want to access the result #453215, you can ask `itertools.islice` to do so and it won't eat up your RAM.

## Improvements

I don't see any benefit to provide the original `[[]]` in your current code. As it assume it is always the starting state. Instead, we could use this parameter at our advantage to turn your code into a solver of partial grids at very tiny cost. The only thing necessary (beside ensuring a 9×9 grid) is to "skip" cells that already have a number in it.

## Proposed improvements

```
"""Sudoku Valid Boards Generator

This module is using a recursive depth-first search approach
to generate every valid board from a starting template.
"""

__author__ = 'Anderson Freixo <anderson.freixo@gmail.com>'
__credits__ = '''Contributors:
 * Mathias Ettinger (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger)
'''

import copy
import itertools


# List of indices (line, column) for each cell in each
# 3×3 block of a sudoku grid.
BLOCKS = [
    list(itertools.product(
        range(3*n, 3*(n+1)),
        range(3*m, 3*(m+1)),
    )) for n, m in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2)
]


def is_in_line(num, board, line):
    """Test if the given number lies in the given line of the given board"""
    return num in board[line]


def is_in_column(num, board, column):
    """Test if the given number lies in the given column of the given board"""
    for line in board:
        if line[column] == num:
            return True
    return False


def is_in_block(num, board, line, column):
    """Test if the given number lies in the given block of the given board"""
    for l, c in find_block(line, column):
        if board[l][c] == num:
            return True
    return False


def find_block(line, column):
    """Retrieve the block which contain the cell at the given line and column"""
    cell = (line, column)
    for block in BLOCKS:
        if cell in block:
            return block


def initialize(board):
    """Ensure a board has at least 9 lines and 9 columns"""
    # Copy the parameter in order to not update it in place
    board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    while len(board) < 9:
        board.append([None] * 9)

    for line in board:
        line.extend([None] * (9 - len(line)))

    return board


def search(board):
    """Generate all valid solutions that can fit in the given board"""

    def _search_helper(board, line, column):
        """Recursivelly try all number for the cell at the
        given line and column and generate the solution if
        the grid has been filled.
        """

        if (line, column) == (9, 0):
            # Reached the end of the recursion so
            # this board must be complete.
            yield copy.deepcopy(board)
            return

        new_column = (column + 1) % 9
        new_line = line if new_column else line + 1
        if board[line][column]:
            # Skip cells that already have a number before the search
            yield from _search_helper(board, new_line, new_column)
            return

        for number in range(1, 10):
            if is_in_line(number, board, line):
                continue
            if is_in_column(number, board, column):
                continue
            if is_in_block(number, board, line, column):
                continue

            board[line][column] = number
            yield from _search_helper(board, new_line, new_column)
            # Reset cell so this number doesn't interact
            # with subsequent recursive searches
            board[line][column] = None

    yield from _search_helper(initialize(board), 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint

    # print the first 1000 valid grid generated
    for i, solution in enumerate(search([[]])):
        print('Solution n°{}:'.format(i))
        pprint(solution)
        if i > 999:
            break

    print('-' * 80)

    # Solve a given grid
    grid = [
            [3, 4, 0, 8, 2, 6, 0, 7, 1],
            [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0],
            [7, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 3],
            [0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
            [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0],
            [0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0],
            [8, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 9],
            [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
            [4, 1, 0, 3, 8, 9, 0, 6, 2],
    ]
    for i, solution in enumerate(search(grid)):
        print('Solution n°{}:'.format(i))
        pprint(solution)
```

---

<sub><sub>grid to solve found [here](http://edulectura.blogspot.fr/2014/07/el-sudoku.html)</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very complete and I'm learning a lot from it . I don't understand completely the code you suggested yet, because 'm still trying to understand the functioning of "yield from".  But besides that, I got curious to know why it isn't ok to implicitly return None instead of returning False in the end of is_in_column() and is_in_block(), and why a deep copy was necessary in initialize(board).

Comment: @AndersonFreixo You can think of `yield from iterable` as pretty much `for x in iterable: yield x`

Comment: @AndersonFreixo and for `return False` vs nothing, it's to convey the intent more unambiguously. But the comment was mostly for the `is_in_line` function.